# A pipeline to extract math equations and process in python

Tags: python, latex, ocr, sympy

I used [latex-ocr](https://github.com/lukas-blecher/LaTeX-OCR) to extract a math equation from an image. I need to process them in Python. For that, I used [latex2sympy](https://github.com/OrangeX4/latex2sympy). But I get errors when I try to connect output of 1 with input of the other.

```
from PIL import Image
from pix2tex.cli import LatexOCR
from latex2sympy2 import latex2sympy, latex2latex

i = Image.open(myfile)
model = LatexOCR()
print(model(i))
# The result is  \sum_{j}^{G}\sum_{l=1}^{M_{j,s p,i}}f_{j}\bigl(X,Y_{\dots}\bigr)^{\star\kappa}\,C F_{j}

t = r"\sum_{j}^{G}\sum_{l=1}^{M_{j,s p,i}}f_{j}\bigl(X,Y_{\dots}\bigr)^{\star\kappa}\,C F_{j}"
s = latex2sympy(t)

print(s)
```

Error:

```
NoViableAltException: None
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

LexerNoViableAltException                 Traceback (most recent call last)
LexerNoViableAltException: LexerNoViableAltException('\')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/latex2sympy2.py in syntaxError(self, recog, symbol, line, col, msg, e)
    139         else:
    140             err = fmt % ("I don't understand this", self.src, marker)
--> 141         raise Exception(err)
    142 
    143 

Exception: I don't understand this
\sum_{j}^{G}\sum_{l=1}^{M_{j,s p,i}}f_{j}\bigl(X,Y_{\dots}\bigr)^{\star\kappa} C F_{j}
```

I was expecting a python equation.